# como clicar no link e obter reposta sem sair da pagina

Tags: javascript, css, html5, node.js, visual-studio

entro no meu localhost e quando clico no link que criei ele vai para outra pagina....gostaria que quando eu clicasse no link ele obtivesse a resposta desse link na mesma pagina, sem sair dela..
irei mostra meu html...não sei o que estou errando!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Exercícios Html</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        Exercícios HTML
    </header>
    <nav>
        <a href="html/exercicios/teste.html">00 -Teste</a>|
        <a href="html/exercicios/temp.html">TEMPPPP</a>
    </nav>
    <section id="conteudo"></section>
    <footer>
        <br>
        Curso Web Moderno
    </footer>
    <script>
        document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(link => {
            const conteudo = documento.getElementById('conteudo')
            
            link.onclick = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                fetch(link.href)
                .then(resp => resp.text())
                .then(html => conteudo.innerHTML = html)
            }
        })
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Seu erro foi usar o query selector, que seleciona a partir de classe, para selecionar um hyperLink que no caso foi o "", caso esse código esteja retornando resposta, então crie uma div e coloque uma classe qualquer, só pra testar, exemplo:

```
  <div class="teste"></div>
  <script> document.querySelector('teste').innerHtml = SeuDadoAserImpressoAqui</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Opa amigo, beleza? Então, você esta tentando fazer uma requisição assincrona? nesse caso, você precisa entender o processo, vou tentar resumi-lo pra você

obs.  Para facilitar o processo, use o jquery, ele faz a requisição pra você, e você só se procupa em posicionar o dado na pagina, mas caso queira fazer ocm js puro, de uma pesquisada sobre requisições XML.

Passo 1 - Verifique com o console log se a pagina que você esta chamando, esta realmente retornando um resultado, se não você só esta tentando imprimir dados vazios

Passo 2 - Após ver oque a pagina esta retornando, tente idenficar oque ela retorna (array, string, object e etc), isso vai facilitar na definição do método de impressão

Passo 3 - Pesquise sobre o metodo de impressão que vai usar para imprimir esses dados na tela.

Esse é o passo a passo mais básico possivel para requisições assincronas;